# Span(S) and Subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra

How can you tell what plane specifically a vector set spans? 
For example S: (1,0,0), (0,1,1). What plane does this vector set span specifically and how can you see that?

Thanks

Comment: It spans the plane $f(s,t)=s(1,0,0)+t(0,1,1)$.  How can you see that?  By the definition of span...

Comment: Great, looks like you know. I don't. So, which plane is it? xy, yz, xz plane?

Comment: None of those.  It is the plane [normal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_(geometry)) to $(0,-1,1)$ which passes through the origin.  Phrased a different way, it is the plane $y=z$.

Comment: Does  (1,0,0) not count?

Comment: Of course it does.  The set of all $(x,y,z)$ satisfying $y=z$ forms a two-dimensional plane.  That is why it is described by $y=z$ with no additional condition on $x$.  Compare this to the line described by $\begin{cases}y=z\\x=0\end{cases}$ which would instead by the span of only $(0,1,1)$

Comment: how do you know that y=z and x=0?

Comment: The line which is the span of only $(0,1,1)$ has $y=z$ and $x=0$ since every linear combination of $(0,1,1)$ (*which in this case means simply all multiples of $(0,1,1)$*) will be of the form $t(0,1,1)$ which simplifies as $(0,t,t)$ which satisfies $y=z$ by inspection.  The *plane* which is spanned by $(1,0,0)$ and $(0,1,1)$ does *not* require that $x=0$.  The *plane* is of the form $s(1,0,0)+t(0,1,1)$ by definition which simplifies as $(s,t,t)$ which can be seen by inspection to be of the form where $x$ is anything and $y=z$.

Comment: Note that the xy, yz, and xz planes are only 3 planes where there are infinitely many containing the origin.

Comment: Is the assumption that I'm setting three equations equal to zero? So that x+0+0 =0 and 0+y+z =0 ?

Comment: The span of two vectors $(x_1,y_1,z_1),(x_2,y_2,z_2)$ will be the set of all vectors of the form $s(x_1,y_1,z_1)+t(x_2,y_2,z_2)$.  There is no "setting equations equal to zero" going on here at all.

Answer (score 0):

Let $V$ be a vectorspace over the field $F$. If $S=\{v_1,v_2,v_3,...,v_k\}\subset V$. Then, $Span S=\{a_1v_1+a_2v_2+...+a_kv_k|a_1,a_2,...,a_k \in F\}.$